# Neural Networks: Does the input layer consist of neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I currently study the Neural Networks theory and I see that everywhere it is written that it consists of the following layers:

- Input Layer
- Hidden Layer(s)
- Output Layer

I see some graphical descriptions that show the input layer as real nodes in the net, while others show this layer as just a vector of values **[x1, x2, ... xn]**

What is the correct structure?

Is the "input layer" a real layer of neurons? Or is this just abstractly named as layer, while it really is just the input vector?

Adding contradicting and confusing photos I found on the web:

**Here it looks like the input layer consists of neurons:**
[image: Screenshot]

**Here it looks like the input layer is just an input vector:**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you're interested - in the following library, there is no real input layer. The network's number of inputs is assigned as number of inputs for each neuron in the first "hidden" layer. The number of outputs, though, is the number of neurons to create in the output layer. I.e. the output layer is a real layer of neurons. This is logical, as for a neuron, the number of inputs is dynamic, while the number of outputs is fixed to be only a single output. Library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/

Comment: "for a neuron, the number of inputs is dynamic, while the number of outputs is fixed to be only a single output" ==> Hence the number of inputs can be defined in the first hidden layer - the network does not have to contain a real input layer. But it does have to contain a real output layer. It also sounds unnatural to create a real input layer with **x** neurons, where each neuron consists of **x** inputs. Creating **x** neurons with 1 input each sounds interesting to me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your question with some mathematical notations that will make it easier to understand than just random images. First, remember the Perceptron.

The task of the Perceptron is to find a decision function that will classify some points in a given set into n classes. So, for a function

```
f : R^n -> R , f(X) = <W, X> + b
```

where W is a vector of weights, and X is the vector of points. As an example, if you have a line defined by the equation `3x + y = 0` then W is `(3,1)` and X is `(x,y)`.

A Neural Network can be thought of as a graph where each vertex of the graph is a simple perceptron - that is, each node in the network is nothing but a function that takes in some value and outputs a new one, which could then be used for the next node. In your second image, this would be the two hidden layers.

What then do these nodes need as input? A set of W and Xs - weight and point vectors. Which in your image is expressed by `x0, x1, .. xn` and `w0, w1, .. wn`.

Ultimately, we can conclude that what a Neural Network needs to function is a set of input vectors of weights and points.

*My overall advice to you would be to pick one source for your learning and stick to that rather than going over the internet with conflicting images.*

Comment: +1 for the explanation. Personally, I disagree with your last paragraph. I think it is a good idea to get information from multiple sources. You can't really claim to be fully comfortable with a subject if you've only read one single author's take on it. And sometimes your understand some sources better than others, so I find it good to bounce around between sources and try to make connections between them.

Comment: @IVlad - I appreciate the feedback. To clarify, my comment was restricted to the OPs point of looking at images for the same concept across the internet from different sources. Different authors explain their images with different pieces of text, and not all of them are always accessible when you google search "neural nets". I'm not saying it should be _only_ one source - you can have 10 books you read, but mixing text/images across them will always be iffy. Perhaps I could've conveyed it better.

Answer (score 6):

> Is the "input layer" a real layer of neurons? Or is this just abstractly named as layer, while it really is just the input vector?

Yes, it's both - depending on the abstraction. On paper the network has input neurons. On implementation level you have to organize this data (usually using arrays/vectors) which is why you speak of an input vector:

*An input vector holds the input neuron values (representing the input layer).*

If you're familiar with basics of graph theory or image processing - it's the same principle. For example, you can call an image a matrix (technical view) or a field of pixels (more abstract view).

Comment: Yes I'm familiar, I currently study for Master degree in CS. The reason I was so confused is that when they show the input layer as a neurons layer, it always has the same amount of neurons as the length of the input vector. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! I roughly remember when I first encountered ANNs and I found it odd as well, everybody draws them differently. However, once you start working on them on an implementation level it becomes clear.

Comment: The input layer is certainly not a layer of neutrons. It’s just an array of inputs. It’s terrible naming. The first layer in a neural network is the hidden layer. Or just call it layer 1 because ‘hidden’ is a silly term as well. Just a legacy.

Comment: @Luke Yes, it's legacy from before Deep Learning, when ANNs were more popular in the context of computational neuroscience (or at least modeling biological processes) where inputs are (hand-crafted) features and not raw data. In this context, the input can also be seen as a neuron since it is also holding a high-level representation. Nowadays, the ML perspective of seeing it as a "system input" is more common I'd say. But in the end, there's no "right" or "wrong" here since rolling back the abstraction of a model isn't generally unambiguous without the initial context of what is modelled.